# select whole node with its attribute value too with xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

hello Everyone i have a strange question (for me its strange). i have an xml file
like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StudentsList>
<Student>
<student_id email="test@yahoo.com">18700</student_id>
<firstName>Jhon</firstName>
<lastName>Smith</lastName>
<address>Dragon Vally china</address>
</Student>
<Student>
<student_id email="LeeSin@gmail.com">18701</student_id>
<firstName>Lee</firstName>
<lastName>Sin</lastName>
<address>League Of Legend UK</address>
</Student>
</StudentsList>
```

when i search that file using xpath in php like

```
$allStudents = $xml->xpath("//StudentsList/Student");
```

it give me all the students in an array with their child node and values like below:

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [student_id] => 18700 [firstName] => Jhon [lastName] => Smith [address] => Dragon Vally china ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [student_id] => 18701 [firstName] => Lee [lastName] => Sin [address] => League Of Legend UK ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [student_id] => 18702 [firstName] => Xin [lastName] => Xaho [address] => Shanghi China ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [student_id] => 18703 [firstName] => corki [lastName] => adc [address] => flying machine gun china ) [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [student_id] => 18704 [firstName] => Kog [lastName] => Maw [address] => Depth of The Hell ) )
```

but as i have an attribute to student_id node i also want to get the value of that attribute too can any one please suggest what to do for that i google a lot but didn't find right answer. they gave examples for selecting parent by its attribute value but atleast i didn't find the one who select it with the whole node of student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access an attribute named `foo` as `$element['foo']`, e.g.

```
$xml = <<<XML
    <StudentsList>
<Student>
<student_id email="test@yahoo.com">18700</student_id>
<firstName>Jhon</firstName>
<lastName>Smith</lastName>
<address>Dragon Vally china</address>
</Student>
<Student>
<student_id email="LeeSin@gmail.com">18701</student_id>
<firstName>Lee</firstName>
<lastName>Sin</lastName>
<address>League Of Legend UK</address>
</Student>
</StudentsList>
XML;

$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach ($doc->Student as $student) {
    echo $student->student_id['email'] . "\n";
}
```

outputs the two email addresses and of course with XPath the code is the same:

```
$xml = <<<XML
    <StudentsList>
<Student>
<student_id email="test@yahoo.com">18700</student_id>
<firstName>Jhon</firstName>
<lastName>Smith</lastName>
<address>Dragon Vally china</address>
</Student>
<Student>
<student_id email="LeeSin@gmail.com">18701</student_id>
<firstName>Lee</firstName>
<lastName>Sin</lastName>
<address>League Of Legend UK</address>
</Student>
</StudentsList>
XML;

$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);


foreach ($doc->xpath("//StudentsList/Student") as $student) {
    echo $student->student_id['email'] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: i can do it when i have to whole file in html table but when i search in the file and i got a record of specific student how i suppose to get its element. i got an array there by using xpath. or is there any other way to search through xml file

Comment: Well, in the array you have element nodes and when you process the array or access a single element in the array you can access the child element as `$student->student_id` and then the attribute as `$student->student_id['email']`. See the added sample.

Comment: Martin thanks i got near but i am still unable to get the value i used $studen->student_id[0]['email'] it returns this and i am unable to go to this value SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => test@yahoo.com ) how do i access that index?